# POST using Code C# not getting the same response as browse submit

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, httpwebresponse

I need to access a webform, by C# code. The webpage receives one combined parameter (74741432599;14/01/1970;1;3997), that redirects to another webpage, where I will make scraping around some tags.

If I access the webpage using a simple html form, like the code below, everything works fine.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="formIntegracaoMatriculaCalouros" name="formIntegracaoMatriculaCalouros" action="http://dsrvwww4/MatriculaCalouros/Seguro/Login.aspx" method="POST">
            <input type='hidden' id='CPFeDataNascimento' name='CPFeDataNascimento' value='74741432599;14/01/1970;1;3997' />
            <input type="submit" name="enviar" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below, using fiddler, I get this header:

[image]

But Its not possible to do it manually. So, we need to automate this access, simulating browser navigation.

Below, its my C# code to simulate the access:

```
public static string SendPost(string url, HttpParameters parameters, CookieContainer cookie)
{
    string postdata = parameters != null ? parameters.ToString() : string.Empty;
    byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postdata);

    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    myRequest.CookieContainer = cookie;
    myRequest.Method = "POST";
    myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    myRequest.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

    Stream sw = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
    sw.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
    sw.Close();
    WebResponse response = myRequest.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    string responseString = sr.ReadToEnd();

    sr.Close();

    return responseString;
}
```

It does a POST request to http://dsrvwww4/MatriculaCalouros/Seguro/Login.aspx. 
My parameter is "74741432599;14/01/1970;1;3997"

Here is my fiddler:

[image]

I can see that the Header is different, and I dont know if this is the problem. I dont know how to make the same Header, by code.

The target webpage is a webform, it uses ajax control toolkit inside, which I know is a big trouble.... So, I need to find a way to get the correct HTML response.

Below is the target page which I need to get by code.

[image]

Once I am inside this page, I will need to make some scrapings, getting some contents, and simulating clicks.

But, my first challenge is bypass this step which is getting the correct reponse.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong ? Any tip to go forward ?

Well, I improved my code anda now, I have this method used to make the post:

```
public static string SendPost(string url, HttpParameters parameters, CookieContainer cookie)
{
    string postdata = parameters != null ? parameters.ToString() : string.Empty;
    byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postdata);

    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    myRequest.CookieContainer = cookie;
    myRequest.Method = "POST";
    myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    myRequest.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
    myRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
    myRequest.Accept = "image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-application, application/xaml+xml, application/x-ms-xbap, */*";
    myRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0)";
    myRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Pragma, "no-cache");
    myRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
    myRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "pt-BR,pt;q=0.5");
    myRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookie.ToString());
    myRequest.KeepAlive = true;

    Stream sw = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
    sw.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
    sw.Close();
    WebResponse response = myRequest.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    string responseString = sr.ReadToEnd();

    sr.Close();
    response.Close();

    return responseString;
}
```

And now, I am getting this header:

[image]

It is now almost the same... except by the Cookies values, that I dont know how to send it by code.

Below is the fiddler when posting by form, with the Cookie highlighted...

[image]

When I do my access using a simple form, we can see that the next page (redirection) is "/MatriculaCalouros/Default.aspx", which is the correct page I am trying to get by code.

But, for some problem is my post by code, the redirection is different... the response I get is from the "/captacao/matricula" page, which is a prove that I am sending a wrong post... This page is some kind of error...

So, I would like to know if the Cookie that I am not sending is the problem or if there are other things to send by code.

Comment: Do i smell an evil bot coming out of this exercise?

Comment: `I can see that the Header is different, and I dont know if this is the problem.` If you can highlight the difference in your post, it may be quicker for us to assist you.

Comment: @mjwills I updated my post... I improved my code trying to send the same POST request by code, but I dont know how to send the "Cookie" (see my post). I dont know also if this is my problem,,, According to some friends, I will not resolve my problem, cause the target page is a webform with ajax control toolkit webcontrols... is it true ?

Comment: I would be Cookies are the problem. Can you check if your cookie collection is non-empty? Do you send a simple get request first to actually get the cookie from the server before you send them back with your post?

Comment: @PawełŁukasik No.. I didn´t. I realize that the cookie is the problem... but I dont know how to populate it. How can I do, to get cookie before sending my post ?

Comment: @Olivertech just send a GET request to the same address. Server should respond with the page HTML but just discard it and grab the cookies for the POST

Answer (score 1):

To make the header in code use the HttpWebRequest.Headers collection, add your headers in there.

Answer (score 0):

My best guest is that your static method is being called from server-side code, where-as your HTML form isn't using a server-side ASP.NET User Control. Try adding runat="server" to your controls, then try posting and observing the difference in how the headers appear.

Comment: Are you sure you understand what is asked here?

Comment: I guess I must not understand what he is asking. It seems he does not understand how to make the header programmatically. If he wants to observe how the header is generated, he should be using ASP.NET Web Forms unless this is ASP.NET MVC in which case he should just use the razor syntax @form or whatever it is.

Comment: `he should be using ASP.NET Web Forms`. So I can not do the same thing with a console application?

Comment: My environment is ... We need to develop a webapi service to be able to get some informations about candidates, using their document and birth date. This service will be consume by our client. There are many endpoints and one of them is this service which will return some informations that will be get from a third system. This third system was made in asp.net webforms, using ajax control toolkit... is seems to be an older asp.net framework version. So, what I need is develop my WebApi service accessing this third system by code.